# How can I filter JSON when searching for a sub part of a string?

Tags: javascript, json, search, filter

I'd like to filter a JSON object client-side. Until then I did it server side with a:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE row1, row2, row3 LIKE %search%`

I want to do the same thing client side with a JSON object.

For example I could have this JSON object :

```
[{'Key1' : 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2'}
{'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4'}]
```

When I use the filter 'ue3' I'd like it to return `[{'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4'}]`

Comment: You object is a JavaScript object, not a JSON object, as there is no such thing as a JSON object. [JSON](http://json.org) is a data exchange format.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. And even if you meant to post JavaScript object literal syntax, you'd be missing a comma. Please post valid code that represents the actual code/data you're working with.

Comment: What's the logic of your search ? It doesn't seem to really make sense. Do you want to look in any property value for your string ?

Comment: Your scenario is very strange: first record has different keys/columns than the second??

Comment: I want to do an all fields search on an array of objects and only return the objects that have part of the search string in one of their fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"I want to do an all fields search on an array of objects and only return the objects that have part of the search string in one of their fields."*

```
var a = [{'Key1' : 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2'},
         {'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4'}];

var b = filterValuePart(a, "ue3");
```

---

```
function filterValuePart(arr, part) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj)
                     .some(function(k) { 
                               return obj[k].indexOf(part) !== -1; 
                           });
    });
});
```

*shim, shim, shim*

---

To make it case insensitive:

```
function filterValuePart(arr, part) {
    part = part.toLowerCase();

    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj)
                     .some(function(k) { 
                               return obj[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(part) !== -1; 
                           });
    });
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot ! My question wasn't quite clear... I'll have to look why it works though.

Comment: @Ping: Check out MDN, and read about [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: I'm checking them out, thanks. Any ideas how to make the function case insensitive ?

Comment: @Ping: Yes, normalize the case by calling `.toLowerCase()` on both values. So for the first line of the function add `part = part.toLowerCase()`, then in the innermost return statement, do `return obj[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(part) !== -1;`. I'll add a case-insensitive function with those changes just to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have this JavaScript object :

```
var array = [
   {'Key1' : 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2'},
   {'Key3': 'Value3', 'Key4': 'Value4'}
];
```

then you can find objects whose a property value contains a string using

```
var searched = 'ue3';
var matches = array.filter(function(v) {
     for (key in v) {
        if (v[key].indexOf(searched)!=-1) return true;
     }
     return false;
});
var match = matches.length==0 ? null : matches[0];
```

Note that IE 8 doesn't support filter but [this MDN article gives a shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

@Ping - you can use the javascript lib DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com). With it, you can do something like this:

```
var data = [
   {
      "Key1": "Value1",
      "Key2": "Value2"
   },
   {
      "Key3": "Value3",
      "Key4": "Value4"
   }
].
res = JSON.search( data, '//*[contains(., 'ue3')]' );

console.log( res[0].key3 );
// Value3
```

Here is a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/s8ZVg/

Notice that the JSON structure is quoted, which as JSON should be.
DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with a method called "search" and with XPath query (which is a standardised query language), it returns matches in an array (empty array if no matches were found).